# How to use jcrop plug-in incase of HTML5 canvas element

Tags: html5-canvas, jcrop

I am new to this canvas stuff.recently in my project,when a user uploads an image on the server the image is being previewed dynamically on the canvas element .Now i want to crop some portion of it.I have used jcrop plugin but donot know how to get the cropped area.Any minor help regarding jcrop usage is also appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use jcrop you don't have to care about canvas stuff.

Just create an image like this

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" id="cropbox" />
```

and jcrop will do the rest. Use it like this (and add the options you need) :

```
$('#cropbox').Jcrop();
```

Full list of options and tutorial on the official website : http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

**EDIT :**

If you have a canvas that you want to crop, then you should not use JCrop but this :

```
drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
```

[image: illustration of the drawImage parameters]

**parameter Image can be a canvas object**.
Then, to extract your canvas to an image, use toDataURL function.

complete documentation available at mozilla MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: If i am using an canvas element than the id of that element must be used in palce of "cropbox" as i dont know the id of the image being drawn on the canvas(it is dynamically uploaded on server and drawn on the canvas).One more thing i want to know how to get the cropped image portion so that i can draw it some other canvas or on itself.

Comment: :Thanks a lot.I got everything according to my requirement by following the above mentioned tutorial by you.

Comment: So you should mark my answer as your solution to close the topic

Answer (score 0):

jcrop-canvas looks very promising: https://github.com/andrewlin12/jcrop-canvas